# Can Cooper pairs be created and annihilated when the pairs flow in an eternal supercurrent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Imagine the Heike Kamerlingh Onnes’s experiment. In a mercury ring (superconductivity below Tc=4.2 K) we establish a persistent supercurrent. Then we organize temperature cycles (T-cycles) for the mercury ring, say from 3K to 2K and back. According to the BCS theory of superconductivity, the pair density decreases at warming, i.e. a not negligible fraction of pairs annihilates; at cooling the same fraction of pairs emerges back. Annihilated pairs lose their ordered supercurrent momentum on the atom lattice reducing the supercurrent; newly created pairs do not experience any electromotive-force (EMF), since the EMF is no longer available in the ring. Hence, the supercurrent must decrease at every T-cycle and dissipate after a number of T-cycles. However, in all experiments the supercurrent remains constant and, thus, the pair recombination (assumed in BCS) doesn’t take place. Do the pairs really recombine in the eternal supercurrent?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you provide references for such experiments for interested readers? Thanks!

Comment: An answer to the question "Do the pairs really recombine in the eternal supercurrent?" is adequate: YES or NO. However, any comments are welcome.

Comment: The first such experiment is made by Heike Kamerlingh Onnes in 1911 http://www.w2agz.com/Library/Classic%20Papers%20in%20Superconductivity/Onnes,%201911-Superconductor.pdf . His cryostat temperature scattering was about 1 K, so his first measurement of Tc for mercury indicated Tc=3K and persistent current. No cryostat device has a perfect quality (i.e. zero temperature scattering) so every experiment with supercurrents is unavoidably such experiment. See also references in the Wiki-note https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_current#cite_ref-2